# Pythonic way to do Ruby-like regular expression replace while evaluating the matched string

Tags: python, ruby, regex, coding-style, block

I have this simple regexp replacement code with a block in it. When Ruby does the gsub
the match is passed to the block and whatever is returned from the block is used as replacement.

```
string = "/foo/bar.####.tif"
string.gsub(/#+/) { | match | "%0#{match.length}d" } # => "/foo/bar.%04d.tif"
```

Is there a way to do this in Python while keeping it concise? Is there a ++replace++ variant that supports lambdas or the with statement?

Comment: It'd be useful to include an example of the intended output for people not familiar with ruby.

Comment: @zeekay: The expected output is in the comment after the second line.

Comment: And I thought the whole thing was gibberish :O

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) accepts a function as replacement. It gets the match object as sole parameter and returns the replacement string.

If you want to keep it a oneliner, a lambda will do work: `re.sub(r'#+', lambda m: "%0"+str(len(m.group(0))), string)`. I'd just use a small three-line `def` to avoid having all those parens in one place, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: I went for the nested def this time, thanks alot! the trick here was the group(0) thing since the default str() for SRE_Match is not as useful as Ruby's to_s()

Answer (score 1):

I'm not well versed in Ruby, but you might be looking for [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Hope this helps